# Ссылки вокруг картинки

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста варианты как можно сделать ссылки вокруг картинки как на изображении ниже
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как один из возможных вариантов:

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5b667a;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 1rem 2rem;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="left">
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <img src="http://cliparts.co/cliparts/yTk/Kz6/yTkKz6LAc.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
  </div>
</div>  
<div class="row">
  <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
</div>
```